# How can I shape my button on android rectangle to circle?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

In generally android buttons are rectangular and on the  mxl file what should I do if I want to make ring shaped or any other shaped button? or is there any tool that assure these to android developers which is open source (for now I'm seeking a ring-shaped button ).

Comment: You can take the short route of using just an image, and provide similar functionality on that image to act as a button, such as touch down and touch up events; changing the image based on those touch events to show depressed or whatnot.  Or there are ways through styles that you can provide the behavior you want with shapes and color formats in xml.

Comment: You should fire up an image editor or try to do it with xml drawables and then come back when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

create a new xml file inside your drawables, and put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="15dp"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#fff" />

    <size
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp" />
</shape>
```

now, use this as your image in an imageButton

You can also take a look at this:
[android-state-list-generator](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/01/26/android-state-list-generator/)